# Convert string format from array to double format in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have problem with convert from string to number. I have array(x,9) of strings, but I need convert (x,6..9) to Double format, because VBA ignore decimal separator - I do not know why... In resource table is 5,6669 and in end table is 56669 for example...

I try this code for writing to end table, but no results...:

```
For i = 1 To rowcounter
For j = 1 To 5


ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i + totalrows, j).Value = pole(i, j)


Next j

For j = 6 To 9
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i + totalrows, j).Value = CDbl(pole(i, j))
Next j

Next i
```

Thanks for your answers ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in data type declaration of the array

My solution was to replace `String` with `Variant`.

Comment: @RonakChaniyara seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
If pole(i, j) = "" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i + totalrows, j).Value = 0
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i + totalrows, j).Value = CDbl(pole(i, j))
End If
```

Comment: Type mismatch - run time error 13...the same error...:(

Comment: what's the value of `pole(i,j)` causing that? Moreover open Immediate Winodw (CTRL+G), type `?application.DecimalSeparator` and press return to see the outcome

Comment: @alf.cz; did you try that?

Comment: ?application.DecimalSeparator
,

Comment: don't get you. what is the value that caused the "Type mismatch - run time error 13" and what's the value of `application.DecimalSeparator`?

Comment: Value of application.DecimalSeparator is "," in Immediate window

Comment: and what's the value of the string that caused the error?

Comment: Nothing...I dont know why, but really nothing... ""

Comment: one more thing: in Immediate Window type `?Mid(1 / 2, 2, 1)`, press return and see the outcome